# which Tex-command can draw a bracket overlap a line?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, chemistry

Please show me a command in Latex which can draw a bracket like that

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex -- page 46 of the documentation -- http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf

Comment: @Solitaire -- would you like to accept and upvote the answer

Comment: The TeX command is `\kern` <negative amount>.

Comment: @wipet thank you so much, that's what I truly need

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{-[@{op,.75}]CH2-CH(-[-90]cl)-[@{cl,0.25}]}
    \polymerdelim[height = 5pt, depth = 25pt, open xshift = -10pt, indice = \!\!n]{op}{cl}
    
\end{document}
```

**EDIT To make bond lines thick and color**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig[
            bond style={line width= 1pt ,blue}
            ] 
            {-[@{op,.75},0.75]CH_2-CH(-[-90,0.75]Cl)-[@{cl,0.25},0.75]}
    \polymerdelim[height = 5pt, depth = 25pt, open xshift = -10pt, indice = \!\!n]{op}{cl}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT2** -- To make the delimiter mov closer to the atom removed the open `xshift=10pt`

[image]

Comment: You might want to replace cl with Cl and CH2 with CH_2.